# How to cancel Form in "onAfterSave" function?

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I am trying to put a pop up which asks for confirmation on clicking "save" button. I want to cancel the form if user has not confirmed. All this happens in onAfterSave function. But I am unable undo the model variable if I use "formName.$cancel()" in onAfterSave function.

Comment: Please share some code or do a fiddle or something.

Answer (score 1):

Since the model is continually updated as it changes you have to make a reference copy of your formModel beforehand (not an instance):

```
$scope.pristineForm = angular.copy($scope.formModel);
```

If the user discards the changes u simply copy the model back and the form will be back to what it was

**Edit:** I now use **[angular-input-modified](https://github.com/betsol/angular-input-modified#demos-and-examples)** instead, simply add it to your app's dependancy list and all your forms will have extra methods to check for changes and/or revert to previous values

Comment: Thanks, But it is working only for once. When I click "No" in the popup for second time, its not working (

Comment: Oh, sorry man, I just checked what I did and I use a library: ngInputModified, where you can simply check if the form has been changed $scope.current_form.$dirty... if so you can just set it to $scope.current_form.reset();
                            $scope.current_form.$setPristine();


https://github.com/betsol/angular-input-modified

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but This is also not working :(

Comment: do you have some code we can look at? I use ngInputModified with a pop-up confirm and it works like a charm. Maybe your form init's is messing with it.